# Explaining the structure of a thesis

Tags: meaning, word-choice, word-usage

The following sentence, and in particular the bold part, has no entry in google. Does it sound natural to native speakers?

> The work in this thesis **is organised around three research themes of
>   current interest** in mathematics.

Comment: Sounds OK to me.  Is the thesis really organized around 3 research themes? If so, then you're OK.  (Hopefully you say more than that in your abstract or intro, however.  And I assume you then go into more detail about the organization.)

Comment: Thanks Drew. Of course, there is more than that in the abstract (but not sure it would be of interest here ;-))

Comment: You can drop "The work in".

Comment: When you say "organised around" do you mean, that the thesis  addresses three themes?

Answer (score 1):

As it stands, I think it sounds natural and doesn't require revision.

Alternatively, you could rework the sentence to actually introduce your thesis:

> *This study draws on three research themes of current interest in mathematics to argue that ...[insert your thesis].*

Answer (score 0):

Or you could write this as heading: "Current interests in Mathematics based on three research themes". And then continue writing your relevant material for the thesis. I hope this helps.